# JavaFX: Add text to TextFlow - rendering issue

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to use a quite simple JavaFX feature, but may be missing something: adding a new `Text` object to a `TextFlow` that is already showing. I created a very minimal working example:

```
public class TextFlowTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TextFlow textFlow = new TextFlow(new Text("One "), new Text("Two "), new Text("Three "), new Text("Four "));
        var layout = new BorderPane(textFlow);
        layout.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            textFlow.getChildren().addAll(new Text("myAdd "));
        });
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 200, 50);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you run the code above, and click on the text it should add a new word: `myAdd` - however it only renders the first few pixels of the first character.

[image]

My feeling is that it is related to the initial calculation of the width of the flow, so I tried `requestLayout` on the `TextFlow` or the containing pane but it didn't help. Shouldn't this just work out of the box? Just add a new `Text` node to the flow's children, which is an observable list, so the flow should update its layout?

Comment: This looks like a bug. I noticed a couple of things: 1. If you add any style to the text flow (I was adding a background color to see the size of it), it seems to work fine. 2. If you switch to a different container (e.g. an `HBox`), it also seems to work fine.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! Worth reporting as a bug? The container solution won't work for me because I want to use a custom layout manager (where the issue originally came up) but with some styling trick I actually might be work around the issue.

Comment: Yes, certainly. Another workaround is to call `textFlow.layout()` in the event handler.

Comment: You might be able to make the `layout()` call in your custom pane/region `layoutChildren()` method. That would be a more suitable place for it. I don't fully understand the bug though, so I don't know if that would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug (which I'd recommend reporting).

Interestingly, it only seems to manifest in a `BorderLayout`, but not in a `HBox`. It also doesn't show up if you add style to the text flow.

If those workarounds aren't usable, calling `textFlow.autosize()` to recompute the size of the text flow seems to work. Since you say in the comments that you're using a custom pane to contain the text flow, you may find a convenient place to do that in the custom pane's `layoutChildren()` method, or similar. As a worst case, you can just call that in the event handler:

```
    layout.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
        textFlow.getChildren().addAll(new Text("myAdd "));
        textFlow.autosize();
    });
```